# copying string from strtok

Tags: c

I need to divide a C string into tokens. I thought that strtok will be my best try, but I'm getting very strange results...

Here is my test program. In this example I will get 3 tokens with "##" separator but when I try to work with the ones I supposedly had copied, only the third one is shown correctly.. the other two look corrupted or something... I don't know... ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define TAM 3 //elements

char** aTokens(char* str, char* delimitador)
{
 char* pch;
 char** tokens;
 int i = 0; 
 tokens = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*TAM);

 pch = strtok(str, delimitador);

 while(pch != NULL)
 {
  tokens[i] = (char*)malloc((sizeof(strlen(pch))+1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(tokens[i], pch);
  pch = strtok(NULL, delimitador);
  i++;
 }

 return tokens;
}

int main ()
{
 char str[] = "30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,##30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,##30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,";

 char** tokens;
 int i;

 tokens = aTokens(str, "##");

 for(i = 0; i<TAM; i++)
  printf("%d -- %s\n", strlen(tokens[i]), tokens[i]);

 //Clean
 //for(i = 0; i<TAM; i++)
  //free(tokens[i]);

 //free(tokens);

 return 0;
}
```

output with GCC on Linux:

```
13 -- 30117700,1,T   <---- ?
13 -- 30117700,1,T   <----- ?
115 -- 30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,
```

I have commented the "clean" section because it provides lots of runtime error too ... :(

Help please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line isn't correct.  `sizeof(strlen(..))` will be 4 (in a 32-bit app) regardless of the length of the string.

```
tokens[i] = (char*)malloc((sizeof(strlen(pch))+1) * sizeof(char));
```

It should probably be:

```
tokens[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(pch)+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are slightly confused on how `strtok` works.

For the most part, you've got it right. However, the string of separator characters that is given to `strtok` is not used as a string per se, but it used more like an array of characters, and `strtok` only cares about these individual characters. So calling `strtok` with the string "#" is exactly the same as giving it "##". In order to tokenize your string correctly, you need to decide on a single separator character to use, or use a different (perhaps custom) tokenizer function that can handle multi-character separators..

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ken. But I'm afraid to report that with just one "#" I get the same result... :(

Answer (score 1):

Standard implementation of `strtok`:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,##30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,##30117700,1,TITULAR,SIGQAA070,1977/11/30,M,1,14000,0.00,6600.00,10.00,2011/09/01,2012/09/01,0|17,0.00,NO,0,0,0.00, ,";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,"#");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, "#");
  }
  return 0;
}
```